# MongoDB Document Validation in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How would one approach doing this (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document-validation/):

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
  { validator: { $or:
    [
       { phone: { $type: "string" } },
       { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } },
       { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
    ]
  }
} )
```

In this:

```
// database.js
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Test = new Mongo.Collection('Test');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first need to define your schema in meteor.

```
Lists.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {type: String},
  incompleteCount: {type: Number, defaultValue: 0},
  userId: {type: String, regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id, optional: true}
});
```

This example defines a schema with a few simple rules:

1. We specify that the name field of a list is required and must be a
   string.
2. We specify the incompleteCount is a number, which on insertion is
   set to 0 if not otherwise specified.
3. We specify that the userId, which is optional, must be a string that
   looks like the ID of a user document.

It’s pretty straightforward to validate a document with a schema. We can write:

```
const list = {
  name: 'My list',
  incompleteCount: 3
};

Lists.schema.validate(list);
```

In this case, as the list is valid according to the schema, the validate() line will run without problems. If however, we wrote:

```
const list = {
  name: 'My list',
  incompleteCount: 3,
  madeUpField: 'this should not be here'
};

Lists.schema.validate(list);
```

Then the validate() call will throw a ValidationError which contains details about what is wrong with the list document.

Comment: Is this using Aldeed's SimpleSchema package?

Comment: it uses simple schema but no sure if it's Aldeed's. you can read more of it at https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html